# Google Apps Script: Server encountered an error. Try again later

Tags: google-apps-script

I am stuck.. Error is thrown @ Line 63 and sometimes at line 50. Both using the appendTableRow() method. I can't find anything wrong.

```
row3.appendTableCell(entryDesc)
```

Link to generated file: [Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KH8pvMC-LN_K9jXHFoxx6pZaayhIwCr4dQsSEJ0seYc/edit?usp=sharing)

Execution Transcript: [Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WDOj_Tu3gumfGy0WzeEG9JEtsq01B5jJnnZVAwSA5SQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I am new so if you notice any "bad practices" feel free to aim a finger.

```
    // Import data from the Calendar to the timesheet document
    function importDataToTS (dateStart,dateFinish,doc) {
      if (!dateStart) {
        var dateStart = new Date('January 1, 2014');
      }
      var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('0k2s9lfibn50scj41gcuurovck@group.calendar.google.com')
      var events = cal.getEvents(dateStart, dateFinish);
      var oldDate = new Date(dateStart.getFullYear(), dateStart.getMonth(), dateStart.getDate() - 1);
      var paragraph = "";
      var totalHoursWorked = 0

      // START --- Text element styles
      // Date
      var entryDateStyle = {};
        entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
        entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
      // Title
      var entryTitleStyle = {};
        entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
      // entryTimes
      var entryTimesStyle = {};
        entryTimesStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
        entryTimesStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
      // entryDescription
      var entryDescriptionStyle = {};
        entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC] = true;
        entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
      // END --- Text element styles 
      var entriesTable = doc.appendTable();
      Logger.log(entriesTable.getType());

      for (var i = 0; i in events; i++) {
    var entryDate = events[i].getStartTime();
    if (i > 0) {
      oldDate = (events[i-1].getStartTime());
    }
    // If it's a new day add a full width cell
    if (entryDate.getDate() > oldDate.getDate()) {   
      var row1 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
      row1.appendTableCell(shortDate(entryDate,4));
        //.setAttributes(entryDateStyle);
    }

    // Add title, start/end times & hours worked
     // Add title, start/end times & hours worked
    var entryTitle = events[i].getTitle();
    Logger.log(i + ": " + entryTitle);
    var entryTimes = shortTime(events[i].getStartTime(),2) + " - " + shortTime(events[i].getEndTime(),2);
    Logger.log(i + ": " + entryTimes);
    var entryHoursWorked = ((events[i].getEndTime() - events[i].getStartTime())/(1000*60*60)%24) + "hr(s)";
    Logger.log(i + ": " + entryHoursWorked);
    var row2 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
    row2.appendTableCell(entryTitle);
      //.setAttributes(entryTitleStyle);
    row2.appendTableCell(entryTimes + "\t\t" + entryHoursWorked);
      //.setAttributes(entryTimesStyle);


    // Add entry description
    var entryDesc = (events[i].getDescription().length > 1) ? events[i].getDescription().toString() : "";

    if (entryDesc.length > 1) { 
      var row3 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
      row3.appendTableCell();
      row3.appendTableCell(entryDesc);
        //.setAttributes(entryDescriptionStyle);
    }

    totalHoursWorked += entryHoursWorked;
    if (i === (events.length - 1)) {
      var lastRow = entriesTable.appendTableRow(); 
      lastRow.appendTableCell("Total Hours: " + totalHoursWorked);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i in entriesTable; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j in entriesTable[i]; j++) {
      Logger.log(i + ":" + j + " " + entriesTable[i][j].toString());
    }
  }

      doc.appendTable(entriesTable);
    }
```

shortDate() && shorttTime()

```
function shortDate(date,n) {
  // Returns a date object as "MMMDD";
    if (date) {
      switch (n) {
        case 1:
          //Jul6
          return Utilities.formatDate(date, "EST", "MMMdd")
          break;
        case 2:
          //Jul 6
          return Utilities.formatDate(date, "EST", "MMM dd")
          break;
        case 3:
          //July 6
          return Utilities.formatDate(date, "EST", "MMMM dd")
          break;
        case 4:
          return Utilities.formatDate(date, "EST", "EEE, MMM dd")
          break;
        default:
          //Full Date unchanged
          return date;
      }
    }
}

function shortTime(date) {
  //Returns time string formatted as "hh:mm"am/pm
  //Still needs to be updated with Utilities.formatDate
  if (date) {
    var hours = (date.getHours() > 12) ? (date.getHours() - 12) : date.getHours();
    var ampm = (date.getHours() > 12) ? "pm" : "am";
    var minutes = (date.getMinutes() == 0) ? "00" : date.getMinutes();
    var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ampm
    return time.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a log inside the loop to see on what value of i it fails ? In my test it is always i=7, don't know why (yet) ^^  it would also be nice to show your shortTime and shortDate functions please. btw, this is an interresting code, I like the result, very neat... cool !

Comment: thanks for the code. what about value of i in the loop ?

Comment: that may or may not be what you asked..

Comment: I can also share the project on Google Docs if you would like to see the whole scope.

Comment: not necessary, I made a working test... did you log the value of i when it fails in your script ?

Comment: yes it's 7 every time. It's consistently on Line 53: row2.appendTableRow();

Comment: That's weird... 7 with my calendar and 7 with yours... at least we can be sure it is not depending on events :-) ... we'll find out!

Comment: hmmm wrong diagnostic from my side... actually error occurs only on some type of events, changing the date I managed to get 50+ events showing up ok and then... error. I'l try to figure out why these events cause the crash.

Comment: I can share the day from my calendar that's causing the error if you want to copy it and test it from your end

Comment: I found the error ! it happens when there is a description length>2 the part with row3 is the part that fails... if you comment it and remove the last doc.appendTable(entriesTable) at the end of the function then everything is fine except you don't have the descriptions... I'll try to find a way to get it, in the mean time please try as I said and keep me informed ;)

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down. I had it functioning flawlessly  before I started adding the text formatting. Than I had made so many changes I couldn't figure out what I did to break it. I'll keep working on it and let you know what I find. Thanks Again!

Comment: I have narrowed it down to multi-line description fields. Still working on a fix.

Comment: good luck ! I posted an answer for another few details that were causing bad results, see the code for total time and duration of events.

Comment: Well I found a solution but my rep is too low to answer my own question: So it appears that:

`body.appendTableCell();`

doesn't handle line breaks "\n". Adding split('\n') to the description row solved the problem.

This worked:

`body.appendTableCell(data).split("\n");`

Thanks Serge for the help. I'll post the full answer after the reqd. 8 hours of wait time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer but I thought it might be interesting in the mean time to show a version that works without the event description.

I changed the calculation of total time that didn't work either.

Code can be tested on any default calendar using test function.

```
function test(){
//dateStart,dateFinish,doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var dateStart = new Date('January 1, 2014');
  var dateFinish = new Date('April 1, 2014')
  importDataToTS (dateStart,dateFinish,doc);
}



function importDataToTS (dateStart,dateFinish,doc) {
  if (!dateStart) {
    var dateStart = new Date('January 1, 2014');
  }
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var events = cal.getEvents(dateStart, dateFinish);
  var oldDate = new Date(dateStart.getFullYear(), dateStart.getMonth(), dateStart.getDate() - 1);
  var paragraph = "";
  var totalHoursWorked = 0

  // START --- Text element styles
  // Date
  var entryDateStyle = {};
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  // Title
  var entryTitleStyle = {};
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
  // entryTimes
  var entryTimesStyle = {};
    entryTimesStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
    entryTimesStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
  // entryDescription
  var entryDescriptionStyle = {};
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC] = true;
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
  // END --- Text element styles 
  var entriesTable = doc.appendTable();
  Logger.log('events.length = '+events.length);

  for (var i = 0; i <events.length; i++) {
    var entryDate = events[i].getStartTime();
    if (i > 0) {
      oldDate = (events[i-1].getStartTime());
    }
      Logger.log('i = '+i);
    // If it's a new day add a full width cell
    if (entryDate.getDate() > oldDate.getDate()) {   
      var row1 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
      row1.appendTableCell(shortDate(entryDate,4))
        .setAttributes(entryDateStyle);
    }

    // Add title, start/end times & hours worked
    var entryTitle = events[i].getTitle();
    var entryTimes = shortTime(events[i].getStartTime(),2) + " - " + shortTime(events[i].getEndTime(),2);
    var entryHoursWorked = (events[i].getEndTime().getTime() - events[i].getStartTime().getTime())/(1000*60*60) + "hr(s)";
    var row2 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
    row2.appendTableCell(entryTitle)
      .setAttributes(entryTitleStyle);
    row2.appendTableCell(entryTimes + "\t\t" + entryHoursWorked)
      .setAttributes(entryTimesStyle);


    // Add entry description
    var entryDesc = (events[i].getDescription().length > 2) ? events[i].getDescription() : "";


    totalHoursWorked += Number(entryHoursWorked.replace(/\D/g,''));
    if (i === (events.length - 1)) {
      var lastRow = entriesTable.appendTableRow(); 
      lastRow.appendTableCell("Total Hours: " + totalHoursWorked+' Hours');
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i in entriesTable; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j in entriesTable[i]; j++) {
      Logger.log(i + ":" + j + " " + entriesTable[i][j].toString());
    }
  }

  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Total hours I broke earlier: removing "hr(s)" from: var entryHoursWorked = (events[i].getEndTime().getTime() - events[i].getStartTime().getTime())/(1000*60*60) + "hr(s)" : and added it back to  row2.appendTableCell(entryTimes + "\t\t" + entryHoursWorked + "hr(s)") works. I haven't touched RegExp yet. This is the first programming project I have started. Kind of 'learn as you go'

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it appears that: body.appendTableCell(); doesn't handle line breaks "\n". When the script was importing a multi-line event description from the calendar I would get a "server error" message. Adding split('\n') to the description row solved the problem. This worked:  body.appendTableCell(data).split("\n");

Finished code:

```
var entryDesc = (events[i].getDescription().length > 1) ? events[i].getDescription() : "";
    if (entryDesc) { 
      var row3 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
      row3.appendTableCell("");
      row3.appendTableCell(entryDesc.split("\n"))
        .setAttributes(entryDescriptionStyle);
    }
```